# proving an abelian group

Tags: number-theory

I am reading this to understand more on abelian group. I could not understand some steps.

https://yutsumura.com/prove-a-group-is-abelian-if-ab3a3b3-and-no-elements-of-order-3/

> "Taking the square of (**), we obtain:
> $$(b^{−1} \cdot a^{−1} \cdot b \cdot a)^2 = a \cdot b \cdot a^{−1} \cdot b^{−1}$$

how was this being deduced?

also, what did it mean by

> The group $G$ does not have an element of order $3$, Otherwise, the order of the element $a b a^{−1} b^{−1}$ would be 3

what did order of the element mean in here?

Comment: I helped you a bit with math formatting (this site supports MathJax), but otherwise this is a pure mathematical question and I can't see any cryptography involved here. I suppose if you search "order", "power", "exponent", "group", or similar keywords on MathOverflow or Maths.SE, there will be some relevant results there.

Comment: See defintion of the [order of an element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)). While this math can occur in a crypto context, this indeed is a group theory question. The main difficulty of the exercise is coming with a $c$ useful to prove commutativity demonstrably such the$c^3=e$ (without using commutativity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A set contains elements. In a group having Identity element e , and if an order of an element p is x then  ${p^x=e}$. which means it will repeat its cycle from x.
for example, if G={1,-1,i,-i}.
Here identity element is 1 say 'e'. so order of -1 is ${(-1)^2=1=e}$ .
order of i is i=4, because ${(i)^4=1}$

Now in your case it tells the if there is an element of order 3 in group say m, then
${(ab a^{-1} b^{-1}=m)}$ But, it is given that there is no such element, hence it is an identity element e.

Comment: Now, your first question.  To prove the group is abelian, he took element a, b and inverse of them as ${a^-1 }$and ${b^-1}$ respectively from the group, and he use the given formula ${(ab)^2=a^2 b^2}$

Comment: The commutator of two elements, a and b, of a group G, is the element ${[a, b] = a^{−1}b^{−1} ab}$. and is equal to the group's identity if and only if a and b commute (that is, if and only if ab=ba).

Comment: After squaring second time you  get ${(aba^{-1}b^{-1})^4=(aba^{-1}b^{-1})}$ , then ${(aba^{-1}b^{-1})^3=e}$,   Hence, stated above the group  is Abelian.

Comment: i tried to write on paper, but i still cannot figure out why this. i am still confusing on why, $$(b^{−1} \cdot a^{−1} \cdot b \cdot a)^2 = ? = a \cdot b \cdot a^{−1} \cdot b^{−1}$$

Comment: As I said in above comments, we'll use the commutator of group elements a,b. i.e., if a, b are the elements of group G, then, commutator of 
a and b is  $${[a, b]= a^-1b^-1ab} \in G$$ , - Now you are given $${(ab)^2 = a^2b^2}$$, use commutator value in this equation  that becomes - $${(aba^-1b^-1)^2= (a^-1b^-1)^2(ab)^2}$$

Comment: in the website, we are given this only > $$(ab)^2 = b^2 a^2$$, could you write down the exact step-by-step of ? in below $$(b^{−1} \cdot a^{−1} \cdot b \cdot a)^2 = ? = a \cdot b \cdot a^{−1} \cdot b^{−1}$$ , this should help me reasoning. thx a lot.